# Filter by one value in unstructured table but sorting by another

Tags: mysql, sql

This is perhaps a fairly straight-forward SQL query, but I've not done much SQL/database querying before and have inherited an issue that I'm struggling to understand and describe properly (thus the vague title....)

```
USER META
======================================
  id  |  user_id  |  field  |  value
======================================    
   1  |     1     |  color  |  red
   2  |     1     |  year   |  1923
   3  |     1     |  ...    |  ...
   4  |     3     |  color  |  purple
   5  |     3     |  year   |  2013
   6  |     3     |  ...    |  ...    
   7  |     7     |  color  |  red
   8  |     7     |  year   |  1982
   9  |     7     |  ...    |  ...
```

Given that I have a table structured like the above example, how would I query for a list of user_id's filtered by a specific 'color', but sorted by 'year'?

*NOTE: I'm dealing with a legacy project, so I'm not in position to make schema changes.*

Answer (score 2):

You can do self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_id
FROM TableName t1
JOIN TableName t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
WHERE t1.field = 'color' AND t1.value = 'red' AND t2.field = 'year'
ORDER BY t2.value
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is with aggregation:

```
select user_id
from usermeta
group by user_id
having sum((case when field = 'color' then value end) = 'purple') > 0
order by max(case when field = 'year' then value+0 end);
```

The `having` clause is counting the number of rows that meet the particular condition, and making sure there is at least one for a given `user_id`.

The `order by` is returning the year.  The `+0` just converts it to a numeric value, so it sorts correctly.  The year is being stored as a string.  (For year, this may not be important because presumably all are four digits, but for other numerics it could be important.)

Comment: Wow, this looks interesting

Comment: Yeah, very interesting! Thanks for the response. I ran both your method and MarcinJuraszek's method above and, at least in my particular case, the JOIN method ran about 5.5x faster on average. (~0.43s to ~2.35s on a table with ~82,000 records)

Out of curiosity, are there situations where this is the preferred approach?

Comment: Also, I had to change the HAVING line to read:
`HAVING sum(value = 'purple') > 0`

Answer (score 0):

I think that one solution would be to create temp tables dynamically, one with columns user_id and color and another with columns user_id and year based upon this table and then do a join on them. Even if you find a syntactically composite single statement solution, it will internally have to do something similar.

It is possible to insert into a table based upon the output of a select. Sorry, I am not giving you the exact syntax here but the direction hopefully helps.

Comment: Really? Do joins in select statements create temp tables?

Comment: Why do create two temp tables and then join? why not just do a self join to the same table which in DBMS concept is a `unary/recursive relationship`?

Comment: @Rahul7, because the un-normalized schema here does not lend itself naturally to the kind of self-joins that you are talking about or so I think.

Comment: @Samir, Really? then what about the answer given by MarcinJuraszek. Do you think that's an wrong answer?